# File SRC Paths Changed Automatically Upon Deployment

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

This issue has me stumped:

I moved my local files from my Xampp to a Bitnami LAMP stack on Ubuntu AWS. I uploaded all using Filezilla. Upon upload my javascript didn't work. I didn't understand why until I looked at the HTML coming from the server.

Instead of my regular paths...

```
<link href="css/tooltipster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!-- Scripts-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="post.js"></script> etc...
```

I got this:

```
<link href="http://myawsip/css/A.SpryTabbedPanels.css+tooltipster.css,Mcc.KFxZEWandq.css.pagespeed.cf.3Swzy938h5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Scripts-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://myawsip/js/post.js,Mjm.gvzSGVXyEh.js+player.js,Mjm.knKxAablGA.js+SpryTabbedPanels.js,Mjm.kvF1NI0-pM.js+menu_right_dynamic.js,Mjm.9vUmreO6tb.js+jquery.tooltipster.js,Mjm.urV6AglKpQ.js.pagespeed.jc.HIUzWcgd7x.js"></script><script>eval(mod_pagespeed_pv1QAJpZL$);</script>
    <script>eval(mod_pagespeed_L2$U6aAm8V);</script>
    <script>eval(mod_pagespeed_5VPbKVMy_4);</script>
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_Sxlhb$9amX);</script>

    <script>eval(mod_pagespeed_0_Dq_37I8a);</script>
```

Could this be because I have a AWS IP? I didn't put in any "eval" or anything else for that matter and I have no idea how all this got in there. I reuploaded, but nothing seems to fix this. The files on my computer have proper links to all the files, scripts or css, but once I upload they are changed.

Any idea what could be causing this problem? Any setting perhaps that I have to set in order to transfer files without this anomaly happening?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) by Google

Since you may / may not have access to the configs. This `.htaccess` change will work

> ModPagespeed off

Comment: Hello Connor. Thanks for the explanation. Excuse my ignorance, but how do it turn this off. It makes my work on the site completely useless.

Comment: Thank you - I commented them out in the httpd.conf.